# cURL with PHP / Working with PUT and GET

Tags: php, curl, openhab

can anyone help me to translate this to a PHP Code:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: text/plain" "https://test:testpassword@domain.com:1443/rest/items/test/state"
```

and:

```
curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "OFF" "https://test:testpassword@domain.com:1443/rest/items/test/state"
```

My attempt failed. Usually I would use this:

```
function sendCommand($item, $data) {
  $url = "http://192.168.1.121:8080/rest/items/" . $item;

  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: text/plain\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data  //http_build_query($data),
    ),
  );

  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  return $result;
}
```

But I don't know how to add SSL Support and authentication to the script and I know that is easier with cUrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sendCommand($item,$itemValue){
        $ch = curl_init("http://[IP from openHAB2]:8080/rest/items/".$item."/state");
        $curlOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/plain','Accept: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => NULL,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $itemValue
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
            $this->updateDatabase(curl_error($ch));
            echo 'Curl-Fehler: ' . curl_error($ch);
            exit();
        }else{
            curl_exec($ch);
            return true;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make it work with https is adding:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

If you want to do it the proper way, you can read [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

For authenticating, there's just one line:

`curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");`

Comment: Thank you, I have already found the way to add SSL and authenticating to cUrl. My problem is translate this:
`curl -X GET --header "Accept: text/plain" "https://test:testpassword@domain.com:1443/rest/items/test/state"`
and 
`curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "OFF" "https://test:testpassword@domain.com:1443/rest/items/test/state"` to a PHP-Script.

Comment: Check the 2nd part of my answer for the authentication part. In your case, it should be "test:testpassword".

Comment: My problem is not the ssl and authentication. My Problem is to convert the curl shell script to a PHP-Script